# Mobile header not changing color

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile, header

The desktop version is fine and changed color, but the mobile version won't change from white to #f3f3f5 (grey). I've changed all the header templates in wordpress, and I've tried some basic code to no avail.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Tom

Comment: Please provide more detail including code changes to the templates and CSS as it is probably CSS within a media query that is your issue.

Comment: Try `! important` in the CSS.
kindly add more details on the question

Comment: Hi fromthehills and Pritam Mullick, thanks for answering, the site is https://logominimalist.com/, and I tried this code - @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
#header_main {
  background:#f3f3f5;
  border-bottom:none;
}
}

Comment: should have added @fromthehills. Thanks

Comment: and @Pritam Mullick, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Pritam Mullick, tried that and it didn't change it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I see that this CSS is impacting your header color in mobile device]

Didn't find a `#header_main`  in your HTML file.